# Can PM2 take an action upon a process being marked "Errored"

Tags: pm2

PM2 will mark a process status "Errored" if it restarts more than "max_restarts" where each restart lasts less than "min_uptime". Perhaps it happens in other circumstances as well.

I'd like to take an action in the event that such a string of fatal errors occur. In my case, I'd like to reboot the whole machine since it means something horrible has occurred. Is this possible?

Note: I now see that it's possible to do this when PM2 is being used programmatically (see answer below). Is there a way to do it automatically through the CLI instead? Something similar to a githook that runs automatically upon the "errored" status being raised.

Answer (score 0):

If PM2 is being used programmatically, this function can be used:

pm2.describe(process,errback)

It returns 'processDescription', which includes 'pm2_env', which includes 'status', which would show 'errored'.

This may answer the question for someone else, but it does not answer the question for me, as I would like to use PM2 via CLI call, and not from within another node script.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but I had the same problem and nowadays, there is a CLI solution:

You can use `pm2 jlist` to get the current process list as JSON and parse it for example with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). To search for all processes managed by pm2 in status "errored", you could call something like:

```
pm2 jlist | jq '.[] | {"name": .name, "status": .pm2_env.status} | select(.status=="errored")'
```